# Maps Place Click save that location to Android Listview?

Tags: android, maps, android-listview

I am displaying the Google maps in the Android program.How can i save the places to Android Listview whenever I Click On  One place in the map.

By this I am Getting the search place in the maps

```
package com.commonsware.android.nooer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class SampleMpas extends MapActivity {

MapView mapView;

MapController mapController;

GeoPoint mgeoPoint;

Drawable marker;

MyLocationOverlay mLocationOverlay;

MotionEvent e;
public void changeMap(String area)
{
 MapController mc=mapView.getController();
GeoPoint myLocation=null;
double lat = 0;
double lng = 0;
try
{

Geocoder g = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

java.util.List<android.location.Address> result=g.getFromLocationName(area, 1);
if(result.size()>0){

Toast.makeText(SampleMpas.this, "country: " + String.valueOf(result.get(0).getCountryName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
lat = result.get(0).getLatitude();
lng = result.get(0).getLongitude();

}            
else{
Toast.makeText(SampleMpas.this, "record not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return;
}
}
catch(IOException io)
{
Toast.makeText(SampleMpas.this, "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
myLocation = new GeoPoint(
(int) (lat * 1E6),
(int) (lng * 1E6));
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
mc.animateTo(myLocation);
mc.setZoom(15);
mapView.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnSearch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText txtSearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMapSearch);
        String area=txtSearch.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(SampleMpas.this, "Click-" + String.valueOf(area), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SampleMpas.this.changeMap(area);

                    }

        });

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

    mapController = mapView.getController();

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);

    marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(), marker
            .getIntrinsicHeight());

    mapView.getOverlays().add(new MapOverlay(marker));


    mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);

    mapView.getOverlays().add(mLocationOverlay);

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (id) {
        case 0:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Are You Want save this place As?").setIcon(
                    R.drawable.icon).setPositiveButton("Favorite",
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog , int which) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    }).setCancelable(true).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog , int which) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    }).setCancelable(true).setNeutralButton("Business", new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    })

            .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismiss",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }).create();


        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
        }



@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


Point scrPoint;


private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat , double lon) {

    return (new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lon * 1E6)));
}


class MapOverlay extends
        com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    List<OverlayItem> ListofGeopoints = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();


    public MapOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker ) {

        super(defaultMarker);
        double lat = 0;
        double lang = 0;
        ListofGeopoints.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(lat, lang),
                "IN", "India"));
        populate();

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {

    switch (index) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GeoLocation : 0",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                showDialog(0);
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }


    String add = "";

    List<Address> add_List = new ArrayList<Address>();


    private void getAddress() {

       /* add_List = ReverseGeocode
                .getFromLocation(35.594227, -105.223618, 2);
*/
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return (ListofGeopoints.get(i));
    }
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return ListofGeopoints.size();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the geo points of the Touched location by

```
  @Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p , MapView mapView)
```

Write a class which derives from the Overlay class and override the onTap() method. Then you can add your overlay to the your MapView. A GeoPoint object, which represents the position of you tap, is passed to the onTap() method when you tab somewhere on the map. Save this Geo points in your DB and populate your list view from the database.

Sample Code: Overlay Class:

```
class MapOverlay extends
        com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p , MapView mapView) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("Latitude" , String.valueOf(p.getLatitudeE6()/1E6));
    Log.i("Longitude", String.valueOf(p.getLongitudeE6()/1E6));


        return super.onTap(p, mapView);
    }
```

Comment: Avoid extended discussions in the comments. Go to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) instead.